# Prove that the following matrix exists.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

> For any n integers with gcd=1, prove that there exists a $n\times n $ integer matrix with determinant 1 such that the first row is just the integers given.

I was working on this problem and my attempt is to do actual construction by the fact that there exists a linear combination of these integers such that the sum is the gcd.

When $n=2$ this comes easily, but when $n=3$ or bigger, I found it hard to construct the matrix needed. Any suggestions? 
Or should I do this just by proof of existence not construction?

Comment: Probably duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2645551/constructing-an-invertible-integer-matrix-given-one-column

Answer (score 2):

Write $a$ for the column vector containing the given integers, and consider the $n\times n+1$ matrix $[a, I_n]$ with first column $a$ and rest the $n \times n$ identity matrix. I claim that using only the operation "add an integer multiple of row $i$ to row $j$," you can transform this into a matrix $[e_1,B]$, where $e_1$ is the first standard basis vector. Then $\lvert B\rvert = 1$ by construction, so $B$ is invertible over the integers, and the first column of $B^{-1}$ is $a$; transpose to obtain the result.

To see the claim, notice that the steps of the Euclidean algorithm between, say, a pair of numbers in the first column, are of the kind prescribed. We can thus apply the Euclidean algorithm $n-1$ times to obtain the result, where after each step, the the first column of the augmented matrix is of the form $[d, 0, \ldots, 0, a_k, \ldots, a_n]$, where $d = \gcd\{a_1,\ldots,a_{k-1}\}$.