# Understand a quotient

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, exact-sequence

Suppose to work in $N=\mathbb{Z}^4$, with $e_1,\ldots,e_4$ its canonical basis. Suppose moreover I consider the element $$t=(1,1,-2,-1),$$ and I want to find the quotient lattice $N/\mathbb{Z}t$: I can consider the exact sequence
$$ 0 \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}t \rightarrow N \rightarrow A \rightarrow 0; $$
I suppose that the first map is given by the $4\times 1$-matrix $(1,1,-2,-1)^T$. I know I should end up with a $3$-dimensional lattice $A\simeq \mathbb{Z}^3$: what I don't understand is how to find $A$ in practice, and how the construct the explicit isomorphism $A\simeq \mathbb{Z}^3$. The problem also is that looking online I should use Smith normal form of (some) matrix, but I don't know which since my first matrix is not even squared.

In conclusion, I'd like to see, with this example, how to show explicitly $A\simeq \mathbb{Z}^3$ (with the explicit map).

I am very sorry, this is my first attempt in this topic and I really need to understand it, apologize for some mistakes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, Smith normal form does not require square matrices - it can work with any size of matrix.

So, you do indeed start with the matrix $A = \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ -2 \\ -1 \end{bmatrix}$.  This is easy to put into Smith normal form by subtracting the appropriate multiples of the first row from the other rows.  If you apply this with the augmented matrix, you find that:
\begin{align*}
\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
-1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
2 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}
A
\begin{bmatrix} 1 \end{bmatrix} =
\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}.
\end{align*}
Now, you just need to follow along with the general proof that the cokernel of a matrix is isomorphic to the cokernel of its Smith normal form: $\operatorname{cok}(A) \simeq \operatorname{cok}(\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}^T)$ via the map $x + \operatorname{im}(A) \mapsto Px + \operatorname{im}(\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}^T)$ where $P$ is the $4\times 4$ matrix in the expression above.

Then, you just need to combine this with the canonical isomorphism $\operatorname{cok}(\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}^T) \simeq \mathbb{Z}^3$, $e_2 + \operatorname{im}(\cdots) \mapsto e_1$, $e_3 + \operatorname{im}(\cdots) \mapsto e_2$, $e_4 + \operatorname{im}(\cdots) \mapsto e_3$.  In this way, you get an exact sequence
$$ \mathbb{Z} \overset{A}{\longrightarrow} \mathbb{Z}^4 \overset{\begin{bmatrix} -1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 2 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}}{\longrightarrow} \mathbb{Z}^3 \to 0. $$

Comment: As in the other answer, this case is considerably easier than the general case from the fact that we started out with the gcd of the elements as one of the elements itself.  It might be useful to work out the same sort of explicit isomorphism for a case such as $A = \begin{bmatrix} 10 & 12 & 15 \end{bmatrix}^T$, or for $A = \begin{bmatrix} 2 & -3 \\ 3 & 2 \end{bmatrix}$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your deep answer, and apologize if I accepted to late your answer. If you wish to help me again, I've just posted a strictly related question regarding the cone projection, see for istance https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3734431/cone-projection
Thanks again and have a nice day!

Answer (score 3):

*Hint:* $\{t,e_2,e_3,e_4 \}$ is a $\mathbb Z$-basis for $\mathbb Z^4$.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I assume it is $\mathbb{Z}$-basis since the matrix has determinante $\pm 1$, and thanks to this I can decompose $\mathbb{Z}^4=\mathbb{Z}t\oplus\mathbb{Z}e_2\oplus\mathbb{Z}e_3\oplus\mathbb{Z}e_4$. Therefore the induced isomorphism simply maps $(x,y,z,w)$ to $(y,z,w)$?

Comment: Your first comment is exactly right. But make sure you use the correct coordinates.

Comment: Here we are lucky that the first coordinate of $t$ is $1$. For the general case, see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2645551/constructing-an-invertible-integer-matrix-given-one-column